# Android returns "E/SysUtils﹕ ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus" when I try to inflate a layout inside an onClickListener

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclicklistener

I have a ListView (radFeeds), which is populated by a SimpleCursorAdapter (newRadAdapter).

```
radFeeds.setAdapter(newRadAdapter);
```

I have then set a `setOnItemClickListener` to the ListView

```
radFeeds.setOnItemClickListener
```

On clicking an item from the ListView (radFeeds), I am animating the item so that its height increases

```
final ResizeAnimation a = new ResizeAnimation(webViewHolder);

a.setDuration(200);
a.setParams(oldParams.height, 1200);
listViewItem.startAnimation(a);
```

After the animation has ended, I am inflating a view inside this clicked `listViewItem`

```
if(a.hasEnded()){
    View detailsView =   LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.details_holder, null);
    listViewItem.addView(detailsView);
}
```

When I click on the listViewItem, the animation works fine and the view gets inflated, however, I get an error on my ADB saying:

> E/SysUtils﹕ ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus

If the user clicks on the listViewItem again, it is supposed to once again run the animation which resizes the listViewItem, but this time, it removes the excess space that I had added, by setting height to 0.

```
a.setDuration(200);
a.setParams(oldParams.height, 0);
listViewItem.startAnimation(a);
```

However, the second animation, which is supposed to set the listViewItem height to 0, doesn't run. I know this is because of the error I am getting

> E/SysUtils﹕ ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus

How can I solve this issue?